# Firebase topic subscribed instance ID's

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi all 
 Does firebase provides such API, so that I can get instance ID's of the users who have subscribed to a particular notification topic ?
 Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: You can read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)

Comment: There is no API to get the list of FCM tokens/Instance IDs that are subscribed to a topic. If you need this, you'll have to track the relationship yourself too; at which point you can consider sending to the individual tokens instead of to the topic.